It's so dark in here and I can change my next badge progress
Need more light! Need to change tracked badge, but can't! ;)
Broken buttons:

Result:

I can't change the tracked badge, because clicking anywhere closes that dialog. The lightbox should probably go somewhere else.

Reviewing edits from a post (rather than the queue) is similarly broken. Clicking edit here:

opens this interface:


It isn't limited to that overlay apparently. Suggested edit overlay is also dark and unusable. I'll see if I can add a screenshot.

This seems to be a z-index issue. Presumably, the popup should have a higher z-index than the dark overlay, but it currently doesn't.

Thanks for reporting this. We will fix it soon! Probably today we will release build with this issue fixed.

This should be fixed now.
